# net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET when using JavaScriptSerializer in ASP net

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, ajax

I am trying to perform an ajax request in ASP, and send the response as a json, using JavaScriptSerializer. This works ok, but however when I do this on a class of my own let us say

```
Class User {
    public String name = "name";
}
```

I always get a

> net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET error, and the ajax request fails.

I am using a webmethod for the ajax request

```
[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
public void dispatch() {
    Context.Response.Clear();
    Context.Response.ContentType = "application/json";

    User[] a = new User[2]{new User(), new User()};
    Context.Response.Write(jsSerializer.serialize(a));
}
```

Any tips?

Comment: "ajax request in ASP"? please post your ajax call

Comment: Disabling antivirus solved the problem.